# Python backtest using percentage based commission

Tags: python, pandas, stocks, back-testing

I'm writing a script to backtest some strategies for a set of stocks using the bt framework for python. In the bt documentation ([backtest module](http://pmorissette.github.io/bt/bt.html#module-bt.backtest)) it says:

> commission (fn(quantity)): The commission function to be used.

So when I run my code

```
result = bt.Backtest(strategy, data, initial_capital= 100000.00, commissions=)
```

I want to pass a function that returns a percentage based commission e.g. 0.5 % of the transaction. Since I don't know the size of the transactions, is this even possible? How would it otherwise be solved, using a set commission?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but unless the price varies too much, a commission on quantity should have the same effect as a commission on price.

Comment: I'm using data since the beginning of 2000 so price will vary quite a lot. But I'm not managing on basing it on the quantity either, how to I now the quantity of the transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a function with parameters for quantity and price. Thus it was easy returning a percentage based on the transaction cost as follows:

```
def my_comm(q, p):
    return abs(q)*p*0.0025
```

Comment: do you know whether it is possible to get a time series of (exact) commissions paid per transaction? i realise commissions are taken into account when one calculates `res.display()`. The same with outstanding cash, do we have a time series of outstanding cash at all points in time?